# RGBA4 format with type GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I can understand RGBA4 with UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 , where each color component will be 4bits.
But if we are using RGBA4 internal format for a texture with type unsigned byte, then how is that interpreted?

What I can understand is here each component will be 8bits , but then what '4' will signify in RGBA4?
Will it consider the first 4 bits of every 8bits/component and neglect other?

Comment: `UNSIGNED_BYTE` is only used when you transfer pixels. That is for interpreting the image data pointed to by your `data` pointer. After GL copies that data into its own internal format, that type no longer means anything. You can copy floating-point image data into a `GL_RGBA4` if you want, GL doesn't care, it is just going to convert the pixel data anyway. Note, since you tagged this ES the discussion is a little different - ES does not support mismatching internal / pixel transfer type (no conversion). I would suggest you stick with a single API for your question if you want a single answer.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman@ I want to ask this query specifically for opengl es 3.0 and related to glTexImage* calls. The specifications shows that this GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with internal format RGBA4 is valid. But when I render the images of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with RGBA8 and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with RGBA4 , both looks different. Thus want to know how this image data is applied for RGBA4 internal format.

Answer (score 2):

the `internalFormat` parameter of [glTexImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexImage2D.xml) is what the texture format is.

If you mean to ask about the `format` and `type` parameters, that's not the format of the texture, but that of your incoming data. the GL will interpret the incoming data type by following specific rules described in the GL specification (8.4.4 Transfer of Pixel Rectangles in the [GL 4.3 core](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20120806.pdf) spec).

In particular, in 8.4.4.1 Unpacking, under "Special Interpretations", the case you ask about is covered:

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated by any command processing pixel rectangles if a mismatch occurs